# How to assign a fetch response to global variable?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```
const loadUsers = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters')
  const json = await res.json()
  return json
}

let chars = loadUsers()
```

Why does it return a promise ? If i try to add await keyword to load users i get an error? So what s the problem here?

Comment: You can only `await` in an `async` function.

Comment: async function always return a promise

Comment: @ChrisLi so how exactly do i store the data from the promise into the chars variable here?

Comment: since its a promise you can add a .then and get the value in callback, or using await

Answer (score 0):

Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function